# How to play video with HTML5?

Tags: asp.net, html

The video doesn't play:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DL_Media" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <video src="windowsmedia.ogg" controls="controls" width="215" height="160">
            <object id='mediaPlayer' width="215" height="160"
                        classid="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95"
                        codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701"
                        standby="Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components..."
                        type="application/x-oleobject">
                <param name="fileName" value="res/Files/test.wmv" >
                <param name="animationatStart" value="true">
                <param name="transparentatStart" value="true">
                <param name="autoStart" value="true">
                <param name="showControls" value="true">
                <param name="loop" value="true">
            </object>
        </video>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: why don't you use canvas http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: @VladimirDimitrov, he appears to be trying to using HTML 5 video with a fallback

Comment: What browser are you attempting to view this in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Make sure your browser is compatible

First, make sure the [browser you are attempting to view in supports the HTML 5 video element](http://caniuse.com/#feat=video).

### Sample code

Taken shamelessly from the [developer site at Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video):

**Embedding a video**

```
<video src="http://v2v.cc/~j/theora_testsuite/320x240.ogg" controls>
  Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
</video>
```

**Embedding a video with multiple sources**

```
<video controls>
  <source src="foo.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="foo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
</video>
```

**Specifying codecs required**

```
<video controls>
  <source src="foo.ogg" type="video/ogg; codecs=dirac, speex">
  Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
</video>
```

Other samples on the site include [controlling playback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Stopping_the_download_of_media) and [fallback options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Fallback_options).

Answer (score 0):

Use `source` instead of object

```
<video controls>
  <source src="res/Files/test.wmv" type="video/wmv"> 
  Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
</video>
```